# AVPlayerLayer resizing

Tags: ios, uiview, avplayer, uipangesturerecognizer, avplayerlayer

I am currently working on a detachable AVPlayer so you can drag it with a pan gesture and drop it in predefined drop zones on your UIWindow. (I know iOS 9 will do that for me...but I have to do it on iOS 8)

I did all the work (moving & decreasing/increasing the size of the UIView where is located the player) and it's working well with the UIView. However, the AVPlayerLayer inside this view is really jerky when I move/change the size the UIView at the same time.

So here is the question: How can I update the layer's frame in a smooth way ? 
I tried using the setNeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange, by setting it to YES.
And I also tried implementing the layoutSublayersOfLayer in which I set the AVPlayerLayer's frame to the UIView's bounds.

Both ended up with lags and really not smooth gestures.

NB: In a really basic project sample, it's working like a charm. (Nothing else in the app besides 2 view controllers, one presenting the player, and there I can start dragging it in the UIWindow...it's perfect). However, in my current application, the player is also presented above everything else, and the gesture is really jerky on the layer only. The rest of the application is made of multiple view controllers but nothing is executed while I am using the player.

Does someone have an idea on how to make it working perfectly? Thank you :)

EDIT: I am using autolayout. The parent view of the AVPlayerLayer has 4 constraints: top, leading, width, height.... the 4 of them are updated each time you drag it using the pangesture. The UIView has the correct values.

Comment: Just a quick question, have you got autolayout on or off?

Comment: I have just edited my post to add this information, sorry I just forgot to mention it.

Comment: @user988168 Have you tried that set `playerLayer.frame = self.bounds` in the `layoutSubviews` of the parent view?

Comment: Already did that as well, the AVPlayerLayer takes the right values... but it is still jerky in my app but not in my sample project.
It might be related to my app.... but it does nothing else at the moment.... i don't understand why it's jerky.

Comment: It's ok, cause sometimes if you take autolayout off in the IB it'll work fine. You could take it off, and if it still doesn't work just hit cmd+z to undo the take off of autolayout.

Comment: I tried removing the constraints per default... and it's still jerky

Comment: I ended up removing all constraints from everywhere.... replacing it with autosizing and frames... Guess what?! It's working like a charm! It's now really smooth :)